# Export reports via MHTML looks bad while sending it by mail

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

We’re creating some simple reports in SSRS that are being exported via Web Archive (MHTML) and pasted and sent by emails to the relevant subscribers.

These are mainly high level financial reports for the management.

My problem is when the data is exported from the report and pasted in the mail, the layout doesn’t look as good as in the report itself.

For example,

The pasted report data looks like:

```
December 13, 2010 (12:00:00 A.M. - 11:59:59 P.M.) 

Total Video Revenues
$0.00

Completed Sessions
0

Non – completed Sessions
0 

Cancelation
0
```

Instead of looking like:

```
December 13, 2010 (12:00:00 A.M. - 11:59:59 P.M.)

Total Video Revenues       $0.00
Completed Sessions         0 
Non – completed Sessions   0 
Cancelation                0
```

The only way I’ve managed to overcome this layout issue is by adding a header into the RDL layout and insert in the header a text box filled with WHITE text (which isn’t visible).

This fixes the issue and the report looks good in the mail.

What can I do ?

I believe that it’s a weird way to solve the issue…

Thanks in advance,

Roni Vered.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

It appears that is a known issue which was fixed in one of the cumulative package updates of sp2.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/935399.

A table in a report that is delivered by SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services with Service Pack 2 appears to be compressed when the report is opened in Outlook 2007